# Seeking Detection Tutorial for Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, references

Does anyone know a good tutorial to learn how to detect objects using Google Earth Engine?

My goal is to find a smart way to detect objects (these objects are plantations in Ivory Coast) using Landsat data.

Here is one example of the plantation I am trying to detect : A Plantain Plantation near Anyama 5.464013217554387, -3.8705557721123736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using NDVI index to see if the plantations are separable from the surroundings. There are plenty of tutorials of how to calculate NDVI using Landsat. Such as this one: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_06

Another good way is to use Random Forest classification. This way you train the algorithm and run it to detect pixels resembling the training dataset. This process is fairly easy and well documented in GEE community. Here's a link to such tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification